# How to use a NetBeans Platform application from another Java application

Tags: java, netbeans, platform

Imagine you have a NB Platform application and you would like to use that application via some other app that you've created.

In essence, how can you learn how to start an application if you don't want to use the NB Platform or IDE. You'd somehow need to figure out the stuff that NB Platform does for you when it loads up a module.

Comment: Are you going to use the code that calls NB platform without NB platform present at classpath and expect it to work?

Comment: It looks like you have answered your own question... you  need to figure out what the NB platform does to support your app and then do that some other way...  That seems like a lot of work.

If you are really lucky, you have implemented your app with a fairly strict separation of UI and functionality... (sometimes read as MVC)... which will allow you to replace the interface framework with little to no changes in the feature code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to Geertjan for these:

http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/using-intellij-idea-netbeans

http://java.dzone.com/news/ide-agnostic-swing-rcp-develop